# "Invalid UTF-8" in Chinese input

Tags: 14.04

I had no trouble installing Chinese in 14.04.1, with Ibus-pinyin and an Arphic font. When I try to input Chinese into a text, I can choose the characters, but what it inserts into the file is a "[Invalid UTF-8]" for each character. I understand there was an analogous problem with login in Oneiric, but nothing mentioned there seems pertinent. How do I get rid of this nuisance? I an a newbie,

Answer (score 5):

Got a fix suggested by [pinyinjoe](http://www.pinyinjoe.com/faq/ubuntu-1404-chinese-ime-problems-faq.htm.) .

The ibus-pinyin package is broken and should be replaced by the ibus-libpinyin package:

```
sudo apt-get remove ibus-pinyin
sudo apt-get install ibus-libpinyin
```

Comment: Note from (almost) 2019 - this package is still a problem.

Answer (score 2):

[Invalid UTF-8]this is what I got, and I go back to the pinying 拼 icon at the top , then select preference, at the "General", toggle whatever setting.. close it, come back to my typing space, at the cursor, you'll be asked to select full/half width, select half and you are done.... I'm not good at Linux but this is how I got around with it..I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS desktop.. (I find that choosing full/half with at preference is of no use to this problem).

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install language-selector-gnome
ibus-daemon -drx
```

No idea why it works :-)

在这里找到的：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873061/cant-input-chinese-in-pinyin-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-14-04-from-12-04

Answer (score 0):

Hit the same error on Fedora 29.
Fixed it by disabling/unchecking 'Use custom phrases' in Preference->Dictionary.
[image]